# How do I batch edit field values in my attribute table?

Tags: qgis-3, editing, column

I'm using QGIS.  I have an attribute table that has some very long attribute names because of a join I did, and it seems to be causing errors when I try and select values using an expression and export them as a new shapefile (see the screenshot).  What I would like to do is remove the "CensusACSBlockGroup_" from each column title, but there are a lot of fields. Is there a way to edit the columns and remove this from all of them at the same time?  [image]

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380404/why-is-my-join-not-working#comment623325_380404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"CensusACSBlockGroup_" seems to be a prefix set during the table join. To change the prefix, you do this in the `Layer properties / Join tab`, check the box `Custom field name prefix` and insert a prefix. I stick to the rule to have the prefix `imp_` , so I always know that fieldnames that start with this are fields imported by a table join. If you uncheck the box, no prefix will be set.

[image]

Comment: Can you use this to edit after the join has been made, or do you have to redo the join?

Comment: The fieldnames change, becaus the prefix changes, so if you have linked the fieldnames somewhere, you probably must change them everywhere you used the old fieldnames